# How to disable the option: Open in new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

How to disable the option: Open in new tab

I asynchronously loading content is responsible for what the code below:

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    init();
    $(window).resize(init);

    $('#floatMenu,#smallMenu').find('>a').click(function()
    {
        var t = this;
        $('#wynik').animate({opacity:0}, 'fast', function()
        {
            $(this).load(t.href, function()
            {
                $(this).animate({opacity:1}, 'fast');
            })
        });

        //$('#wynik').load(this.href);

        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

    }).first().click();
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="list-group" id="smallMenu">
                <a href="text/bc/5" onclick="return false;" class="list-group-item active">TEXT</a>
                <a href="text/bc/1" onclick="return false;" class="list-group-item">TEXT</a>
                <a href="text/bc/2" onclick="return false;" class="list-group-item">TEXT</a>
                <a href="text/bc/3" onclick="return false;" class="list-group-item">TEXT</a>
                <a href="text/bc/4" onclick="return false;" class="list-group-item">TEXT</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3" id="menu-padding-top">
            <div class="list-group" id="floatMenu">
                <a href="text/bc/5" onclick="return false;" class="list-group-item active">TEXT</a>
                <a href="text/bc/1" onclick="return false;" class="list-group-item">TEXT</a>
                <a href="text/bc/2" onclick="return false;" class="list-group-item">TEXT</a>
                <a href="text/bc/3" onclick="return false;" class="list-group-item">TEXT</a>
                <a href="text/bc/4" onclick="return false;" class="list-group-item">TEXT</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div id="wynik">
                {* Here is content loading. *}
            </div>
        </div>                   
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried swapping  to  (jQuery code as well) and  href to data-href - does not work.

Comment: add `preventDefault()`:
`$('#floatMenu,#smallMenu').find('>a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); /* your code */
})`

Comment: As a user, I hate sites that prohibit “Open in new tab” feature, as I use it mostly.

Comment: Why do you want to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

... try to add `preventDefault()` inside the `.click()` handler. Without it when you click the link the browser navigate to the page indicate to the href attribute.

Add this line:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

in your code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    init();
    $(window).resize(init);

    $('#floatMenu,#smallMenu').find('>a').click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault(); //ADD HERE
        var t = this;
        $('#wynik').animate({opacity:0}, 'fast', function()
        {
            $(this).load(t.href, function()
            {
                $(this).animate({opacity:1}, 'fast');
            })
        });

        //$('#wynik').load(this.href);

        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

    }).first().click();
});
```

now you block the loading of a new page. And javascript perform your handler without redirect you in a new page.

[AN EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4630gdb1/)...

Comment: Funny that, in your example, the "normal" link does not work on long click whereas the "preventDefault" link works normally at long click, with the item "Open in a new tab".

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `event.preventDefeult()` function on the first line of your handler, like this:

```
$('#floatMenu,#smallMenu').find('>a').click(function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();

    var t = this;
    $('#wynik').animate({opacity:0}, 'fast', function()
    {
        $(this).load(t.href, function()
        {
            $(this).animate({opacity:1}, 'fast');
        })
    });

    //$('#wynik').load(this.href);

    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

}).first().click();
```

Comment: Do you have a working example?